# When storing a MySQL connection string in App.config, what value should the providerName property be set to?

Tags: .net, mysql, app-config

When storing a MySQL connection string in App.config, what value should the providerName property be set to?

For example in the below App.config file, what value should I use for the providerName? Does it matter?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MySQL" connectionString="SERVER=8.8.8.8; DATABASE=foo; UID=bar; PASSWORD=foobar" providerName="WhatGoesHere?" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MySQL" connectionString="SERVER=8.8.8.8; DATABASE=foo; UID=bar; PASSWORD=foobar" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: What is the UID? is it the database user?

Comment: @mukamaivan yes, it's dabase user. UID = Unique IDentifier