# How to give default connection string for mysql database in app.config using c#

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net, connection-string

How to give default connection string for MySQL database in app.config so that when i install MySQL in other systems default connection string must be accepted .For example for sql server we use data source:. as default connection for multiple systems.i need same connection string for MySQL in app.config

Comment: I looks like that is already answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607334/when-storing-a-mysql-connection-string-in-app-config-what-value-should-the-prov

Comment: I have tried by placing the code in app.config but not working. I Need default connection to be worked in all systems when mysql had been installed in their respective systems@Lance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to install a MySql Server in user machine, you will have to specify a User and Password as root for the server. Just then use the connection string:

"server=127.0.0.1;user id=*User*;password=*Password*;database=*Db*"

Where *User* is the Username you specified, *Password* is the Password you specified, and *Db* is your DataBase. The IP 127.0.0.1 points to the local machine (localhost).

It's important to take care of some things: If you intend to install in a lot of machines, and some of that machines has a chance to already have a server installed, you will need to handle this, just google about.

Also, you may need to perform a silent installation. Here are some examples about how to do it:

http://hamidseta.blogspot.com.br/2008/05/install-mysql-server-50-silently.html
http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,26486,42152#msg-42152

> mysqlmonitor-version-windows-installer.exe --optionfile options.server.txt

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?11,26486,42152#msg-42152
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-config-wizard-cmdline.html

After that, You can set your application to use this installation using the approach I exposed in my previous answer.

Note: I'll recommend you to use another kind of server. Since we are talking about Windows, why not use MS SQL Server express? It's free, fast and lighter. Also, I bet it'll be a lot more easier to integrate with your application:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/26/sql-server-sql-server-express-a-complete-reference-guide/
[Can I deploy SQL Server Express with my desktop application just like builtin database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442635/can-i-deploy-sql-server-express-with-my-desktop-application-just-like-builtin-da)
http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/database.aspx
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/products/sql-server-editions/sql-server-express.aspx

**If you don't need more than 10GB of data, I strongly recommend you to use MSSQL express!**

Previous Answer:

In App.config:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key ="MySqlConnectionString" value = "server=*Server.com*;user id=*User*;password=*Password*;database=*Db*;persist security info=True;"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

In C# (I guess you are using the Mysql Connector library):

```
var objConnection = New MySqlConnection();
objConnection.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MySqlConnectionString"];
```

Just remember that exposing the connection string of Your DataBase in Client Machines is a extremely security risk!

Comment: I have tried by placing the code in app.config but not working. I Need default connection to be worked in all systems when mysql had been installed in their respective systems and also i am using mysql connector library @Vitox

Comment: Have You placed the key in the right place? It's not just copy and paste the setting at the end of code. You need to find configuration tag, then find the appSettings tag, then place the new key inside it.
By the way, what's the exactly problem that you had using this code?

Comment: yah i have placed in right place .How to give default password and username of mysql in app.config (i,e) default connection string so that it should work in all systems when client installs mysql.is it possible to give default connection string my aim is to access .mdf file which contains mysql data base in app.config using c#@Vitox

Comment: I'm afraid that it's not clear what do you want. You say about the default connection string. You mean the connection string you want to define as default, or the connection string to connect in a fresh installation of MySql Server in the client machine?

Comment: yes for every fresh installation of MySQL Server in the client machines.it should take default connection @Vitox