# Encrypt App or Web.config using aspnet_regiis - Section 'xyz' not found

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, encryption, config

My app.web.config has custom config section `NameValueSectionHandler`, but aspnet_regiis cannot find it.

I need to deploy my WPF app to multiple machines with its app.config encrypted. I already tried many walkthrough with aspnet_regiis but nothing works. I tried:

1. Rename app.config to app.web.config
2. create public key container `aspnet_regiis -pc LiteContainer -exp`
3. I'm stuck at encrypting the custom config section `aspnet_regiis -pef connectionSettings D:\Tes -prov LiteProvider`

The error is

> "The configuration section 'connectionSettings' was not found". 
> Failed!

But I successfully can read/write data to this section by code.

App/Web.config

```xml
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="connectionSettings" type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>

      <sectionGroup name="userSettings" .... </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>

    <connectionSettings>
      <server>192.168.1.xxx</server>
      <database>myDb</database>
      <uid>root</uid>
      <pwd>123</pwd>
    </connectionSettings>

  <configProtectedData>
    <providers>
      <add name="LiteProvider"
           keyContainerName="LiteContainer"
           useMachineContainer="true"
           description="Uses RsaCryptoServiceProvider to encrypt and decrypt"
           type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider/>
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>
</configuration>
```

I haven't seen any walkthrough encrypt `NameValueSectionHandler` before, many used `applicationSettings` or `connectionStrings`. What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: Hang on, why are you using **aspnet_regiis** on a WPF's app.config? Ok, I didn't realise you could do that, are you following these exact steps? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3b5a1d1f-aa57-40d8-8607-fee0b2a8a6db/protect-appconfig-file-or-encrypt?forum=winforms

Comment: coz many said it's possible and it's okay to temporarily rename it to ``web.config`` and later rename back to ``.config``. Plus aspnet_regiis only works with ``web.config``

Comment: I've tried those steps

Comment: Is **D:\Tes** the folder containing your web.config?

Comment: Yes it is located in ``D:\Tes``

Comment: type="System.Configuration.RsaProtectedConfigurationProvider/> missing end "

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your command is wrong, even if the folder D:\Tes contains your web.config:

`aspnet_regiis -pef connectionSettings D:\Tes -prov LiteProvider`

You've mis-typed **connectionSettings** instead of the **connectionStrings**:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "connectionStrings" <full path to directory containing web.config file>
```

> isn't the syntax aspnet_regiis -pef [section name] [web.config path] ? the section name is connectionSettings not connectionStrings

---

Here is the result when I try it on my PC.

1. Copy an App.Config with AppSettings (*or ConnectionStrings*) sections to C:\Temp, and rename it to Web.config.
2. Run this command:
   %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_regiis -pef "appSettings" c:\Temp

[image]

After running the aspnet_regiis command the appSettings is encrypted:

[image]

3. Rename the C:\Temp\Web.Config to App.Config

## Solution

Your XML isn't the format expected, eg:

```
<server>192.168.1.xxx</server>
  <database>myDb</database>
  <uid>root</uid>
```

Use the standard appSettings or connectionStrings format:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="server" value="192.168.1.xxx"/>
    <add key="database" value="myDb"/>
    <add key="uid" value="root"/>
    <add key="pwd" value="123"/>
</appSettings>
```

REF: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3b5a1d1f-aa57-40d8-8607-fee0b2a8a6db/protect-appconfig-file-or-encrypt?forum=winforms

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.appsettings?view=netframework-4.7.2

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: isn't the syntax ``aspnet_regiis -pef [section name] [web.config path]`` ? the section name is ``connectionSettings`` not ``connectionStrings``

Comment: @Suwandy +1 let me check in a cmd window

Comment: @Suwandy see my edit, change the XML format. *Also accepting answers earns you 2 reputation pts, once you have 15 rep you get up-vote and flag privileges*.

Comment: I'm still figuring out from where does your ``appSettings`` section came from. How did you declare that section?

Comment: @Suwandy I just wrote it. In VS2017 there is a dialogue/window somewhere you can use to add AppSettings or ConnectionStrings. I just followed the same format for AppSettings or ConnectionStrings with the Key/Value XML pairs the config file expects. So just manually copy **my** version of *your* appSettings and manually enter it in the app/web config.

Comment: @Jeremy_Thompson +1 for efforts. Ok this is weird. app.web.config without having ``appSettings`` or ``connectionStrings`` in the file, aspnet_regiis can recognize & encrypt these sections. It produced ``web.config`` file with encrypted content, but app.web.config left untouched. If i rename ``appSettings`` to any arbitrary name ``connectionSettings`` this doesn't work.

Comment: @Jeremy_Thompson i think ``appSettings`` and ``connectionStrings`` are default sections that always exist in app.config file. The reason i'm not using ``connectionStrings`` is this app use .net4.0 & VS2015 i can't install any compatible mySql connector. I can't choose correct DataSource/DataProvider

Comment: I'd recommend you use the standard AppSettings or ConnectionStrings and in C#, `ConfigurationManager.AppSetting["server"]` or `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connstring"].ConnectionString` as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings?view=netframework-4.7.2

Both these config setting sections work in any .Net project 2.0 and above.

Comment: @Jeremy_Thompson Recap: The renamed file should be ``web.config`` not ``app.web.config``. The original question is "encrypt custom  section", not encrypt known existing section (appSettings / connectionStrings). Technically, your solution does not answer the original question, **however** your solution works for me. I removed my custom section and manually type in ``connectionStrings``. aspnet_regiis has no problem detecting this section and encryption with custom provider works fine.
Thank you for your support & effort Jeremy!

Comment: What stopped me from using ``connectionStrings`` before was i can't create it through solution > properties > settings as it asked for valid DataProvider and no MySql selection exist. I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607334/when-storing-a-mysql-connection-string-in-app-config-what-value-should-the-prov) helps me manually type in ``connectionStrings``